# Check if a dictionary keys contain a substring in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a very large dictionary. I am trying to find out if a sub-string exists in my dictionary keys without looping through the keys. Here is an example of what I am doing now:

```
my_dict = {"Apple": 56, "Orange": 23}
if [True for key in my_dict.keys() if "App" in key]:
    print("found.")
```

However, I am wondering if there can be a more efficient way than this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is a small improvement because it doesn't build a list and exits on the first hit:

```
my_dict = {"Apple": 56, "Orange": 23}

if any("App" in key for key in my_dict.keys()):
    print("found.")
```